# select in(past 10 hours and 5 hours)

Tags: php

if the user in the 5 hours has more calls in the past 10 hours, then he should tell me as an example "true". If not, he should say false to me.

```
if($aufruf = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT 
        profil_aufrufe.id,
        profil_aufrufe.user_id,
        profil_aufrufe.aufrufer_id,
        profil_aufrufe.date
    FROM 
        profil_aufrufe
    WHERE 
        profil_aufrufe.user_id = :user_id AND profil_aufrufe.date ..."
))
```

I thought for a long time, but found no way how I can write the SQL code.

Comment: what kind of database?  what do you want returned, something like `user_id` and `called_in_the_5_hours_has_more_calls_in_the_past_10_hours`?  And what on earth does that mean?

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
if($aufruf = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT 
        profil_aufrufe.id,
        profil_aufrufe.user_id,
        profil_aufrufe.aufrufer_id,
        profil_aufrufe.date
    FROM 
        profil_aufrufe
    WHERE 
        profil_aufrufe.user_id = :user_id AND profil_aufrufe.date ..."
))
```

first of all you can't take a column **date** in your mysql table its reserved keyword of mysql 
[date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)
and why are you using alias whenever you don't join any table, there is no need of alias i simplify it i change column date to cdate

```
if($aufruf = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT 
        id,
        user_id,
        aufrufer_id,
        cdate
    FROM 
        profil_aufrufe
    WHERE 
        user_id = :user_id AND 
        cdate between DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 HOUR) and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR) "));
```

I think this will work for you